# Отчет по сети AdMob [Unity][Google play console]

Tags: c#, unity3d, google-play, admob

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему (на скрине) запросов сети намного больше чем сопоставимых?
С чем это может быть связано?
Реклама показывается нормально. Используется Admob Interstitial и Admob banner.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того чтобы понять, какой показатель, что значит. Можно посетить документацию [AdMob](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6158845?hl=ru). Предполагаю, что "запрос" - это запрос на загрузку рекламы. Т.е. заходя в приложение вы отправляете запрос на получение рекламного объявления. А "Сопоставленный запрос", наверное, когда вы у полученной рекламы вызываете "show". Т.е. вы либо не показываете ту рекламу, которую получили после загрузки, либо где-то очень часто вызываете эти самые загрузки.
Попробуйте создать новое приложение. Вызвать дважды загрузку и один раз показ. После чего заглянуть в статистику.